# How do I render a heist template with splices?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework, heist

I'm trying to use `renderWithSplices` - http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-1.0.0.0/docs/Snap-Snaplet-Heist.html#v:renderWithSplices

What is an idiomatic way to get a value of type `Splices s` (for the second parameter to `renderWithSplices`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [heist tutorial](http://snapframework.com/docs/tutorials/compiled-splices) has a couple examples of defining the `Splices` type.

If you click on the `Splices` link in the haddock you linked to above, we see that `Splices` is defined as follows:

```
type Splices s = MapSyntax Text s
```

If you then click on the `MapSyntax` link, you're taking to the docs for the `map-syntax` package.  This is a small package defining some more convenient syntax for creating maps.  There's an example at the top, but the general pattern is as follows:

```
mySplices = do
    k1 ## v1
    k2 ## v2
```

Since the previous definition told us that the keys are text, we can do the following to find out what the type of the values needs to be:

```
someFunc = do
    ...
    renderWithSplices "my-template" mySplices
    ...

mySplices = do
    "foo" ## I.textSplice "bar"
```

If you have a recent enough GHC (I think 7.8 or higher), the underscore on that last line will create a type hole and cause the compiler to tell you what the type of the thing in that location should be.  Then you can write the appropriate thing of that type and it should be more obvious what to do from there.

Comment: I do appreciate your answer, however upon multiple attempts I seemed to go down a rabbit hole with the types (I do not have much experience with monad transformers and kept battling with the HeistT type).

Regarding `mySplices` - it seems that `k1, v1, k2 ,v2` can not just be strings / text values?

Comment: I can't really give you a better answer without more context (ideally actual code) about precisely how you are trying to use Heist.

Comment: I had difficulty understanding how to get a value of `Splice s` for `v1` or `v2` in the example.

I was attempting to just use a string, so I eventually figured I just needed `I.textSplice` for that purpose like so: `"k1" ## I.textSplice "exampleValue"`.

I think it would add clarity to the answer if you had an actual value rather then a type hole (for `k1`, `v1` etc.)